# Error al correr aplicación en flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, sqlite, vscode, app

Estoy realizando una aplicación móvil en Visual Studio Code con Flutter, pero al momento de intentar correr mi proyecto me muestra el error que aparece en la imagen de abajo.
Pero no sólo es con mi aplicación, sino que también intente desplegar la aplicación que tiene por defecto y me marca el mismo error. Ya busque en todos lados y no encuentro respuesta a este error, espero alguien pueda ayudarme.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si pones Flutter doctor en la consola, ¿Qué te muestra?

Comment: Holaa, gracias por responder. Mira esto es lo que me muestra.

Comment: PS C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\Proyecto de verdad-v3> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.9, on Microsoft Windows [Versi¢n 10.0.22000.1219], locale es-MX)
Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)

Comment: [√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Comment: Tuve que ponerlo en partes porque no sabía como agregar una screenshot.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Te recomiendo que el flutter doctor lo pongas como código en tu pregunta, pero viendo, ahí te dice que hace falta "Desktop development with c++" y a su vez, también te da el link para que lo descargues, una vez que descargues haces un flutter doctor nuevamente y ese error ya no debería mostrarse